# Fullcalendar: Correct JSON feed not beeing displayed after update

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I´m having problems updating FullCalendar from Version 1.4.7 to 1.6.3:

The events aren´t being loaded anymore. I´m using an SQL-Server database via JSON feed. Here´s an example String:

```
[{id: '1',title: 'nfhnjzd',start:  1376344800,end: 1376344800,allDay:true,description: ''}]
```

The string above worked out with fullcalendar 1.4.7. and is also being loaded correctly via GET, but the event is not displayed in the calendar.

Steps I took based on the working version:

- updated fullcalendar.css from 1.4.7 to 1.6.3
- updated fullcalendar.min.js from 1.4.7 to 1.6.3
- updated jquery-1.3.2.min.js to jquery-1.10.2.min.js

I´ve been looking for answers in the web for ages now and can´t find a solution. It can´t really be the JSON string, can it? If I create a new event it is also written to database, but if I reload the page, the event disappears again eventhough it´s in the database.

No errors are displayed in firebug. The only thing I can see is the GET statement with the correctly filled JSON feed, which works if I hardcode it in the working version.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I´ve solved this now. After receiving the error

```
JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'.
```

changing the result string of the JSON feed from

```
[{id: '2',title: 'zhdtjtjdzh',start:  1376344800,end: 1376431200,allDay:true,description: 'zjmhztdzhj'}
```

to

```
[{"id": "2","title": "zhdtjtjdzh","start":  1376344800,"end": 1376431200,"allDay":true,"description": "zjmhztdzhj"}
```

did the job. The only thing I did was to change the quoting. So, after all it unexpectedly was the JSON feed. Have the requirements for JSON elements changed? As already stated in my main question above, the generated JSON feed without quotes worked well when used with the old fullcalender and older jquery versions. I´m a bit confused now...